# JavaFx table view, table gateway pattern and join

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx

For working with data from database I implemented table data gateway. So, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
   id INT,
   id groupId,
   name VARCHAR(100),
   surname VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE group (
   id INT,
   name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

And I have two DTO. It's strictly that one DTO for one table

```
class Student{
   private int id;
   private int groupId;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   //+getters and setters
}

class Group{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   //+getters and setters
}
```

And I have two TableDataGateway classes that loads and saves DTO to DB.

```
class StudentTableDataGateway extends AbstractTableDataGateway{
....
}
class GroupTableDataGateway extends AbstractTableDataGateway{
....
}
```

Now I want to create student table via javafx with the following columns:

```
|Student ID|Student Name|Student Surname|Group Name|
```

And here I stop. I can't understand how to build data for table view and what I should do next. Please help me.

**EDIT 1**
The most difficult part (what confuses me most of all) is how to link getting data from group object in student object? Because, it's very undesirable to make in Student class field "private Group group". The reason is that if we for every tableview will modify domain classes they will be very bad. For example if we need to create another table view with columns:

```
|student name|student surname|teacher name
```

Then will we add one more field to Student class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have getters the only thing you need to do is create set table properties for your table. Example:

```
TableView<Student> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Student,Integer> userId = new TableColumn<>("User Id");
userId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
```

this will look for `getId()` in your Student object class and add data from it.

The only tricky part is Group Name because it is in different class. I would probably just include helper method in Student class. You don't need to have any property there. Just need to have getter-like method

```
  public String getGroupName() {
      return ""//Code to find group name here;
  }
```

and here is all the code you need in this case:

```
    ObservableList<Student> students = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    students.addAll(one);

    TableView<Student> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Student,Integer> userId = new TableColumn<>("User Id");
    userId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

    TableColumn<Student,String> groupName = new TableColumn<>("Group Name");
    groupName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("groupName"));
    TableColumn<Student,String> name = new TableColumn<>("User Name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn<Student,String> surname = new TableColumn<>("User Surname");
    surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("surname"));

    table.getColumns().addAll(userId,groupId,name,surname);
    table.setItems(students);
```

but there are always other options for groupName:

1) create custom CellValueFactory and setCellValueFactory()

```
   groupName.setCellValueFactory(data->{
           Student student = data.getValue();
           String strGroupName = "";// calculate group name for...
           return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(strGroupName);
        }
    );
```

2) create buffer object with all the getters you need

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mean to add method "public String getGroupName()" in class Student? If yes, what is the better way to link getting data from group object in student object? I think its the most difficult part. Because, it's very undesirable to make in Student class field "private Group group". The reason is that if we for every tableview will modify domain classes they will be very bad. For example if we need to create student name,student surname, teacher name. Then will we add new field to Student class?

Comment: I added other option explanation in the post: create custom CellValueFactory and setCellValueFactory(). take a look. Hope this will help